# Wrong characters when doing new Date.toString() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I found that, when writing this to Chrome or Opera console with Javascript,

```
console.log(new Date());
```

the result is something like:

```
Thu Mar 17 2016 18:09:25 GMT+0100 (Hora estÃ¡ndar romance)
```

Notice that `estÃ¡ndar` string. It should say "estándar" which means standard in spanish. I tried to discern if it was something about the console, so I wrote:

```
document.body.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
```

and the result was the same. The `UTF-8` meta tag is in the head tag, so I thought this was really strange. I was worried that this could affect strings that I write as well, so I tested this:

```
var str = "Hora estándar romance";
console.log(str);
```

But the output was correct this time. No mistakes. This should mean that my spanish strings are safe but I wonder about the difference between the string that `new Date().toString()` returns and my own string. What is the difference? Is this a browser error?

Answer (score -1):

use date.toLocaleDateString() to localize your dates.